# File tree comparator

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I need compartor to sort Path objects in following way:

- directories go first
- directories and files are sorted in lexicographic order (case-insensitive).

i tried something like this:

```
public int compare(Path a, Path b) {
    File aFile = a.toFile();
    File bFile = b.toFile();

    if (aFile.isDirectory() && bFile.isFile()) {
        return -1;
    }

    return a.compareTo(b);
}
```

it Gives directories in correct order and files after all directories, but its not what i need. Also i tried to compare by file depth and file type (directory or file) but no success at all.

See example below: 
[image: Tree view]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems are you facing?

Comment: @Amongalen i updated description. I will be approciated for help.

Comment: Could you tell us why you need this comparator? Are you trying to flatten the file hierarchy? To display files in a custom widget? There may be better ways than relying on a Comparator and better data structures than (I guess) a list to store the result.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three cases we need to check:

- `Path a` is a directory and `Path b` is not. (So: `a < b`)
- `Path b` is a directory and `Path a` is not. (So: `b < a`)
- otherwise both `Path a` and `Path b` are of the same kind (both are either directories or files) and we compare them by their names.

Putting this into code:

```
@Override
public int compare(Path a, Path b) {
    final File aFile = a.toFile();
    final File bFile = b.toFile();

    if (aFile.isDirectory() && !bFile.isDirectory()) {
        return -1;
    } else if (!aFile.isDirectory() && bFile.isDirectory()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return a.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(b.toString());
    }
}
```

Note, that for case-insensitive comparison we are converting `Path` to `String` and using `String#compareToIgnoreCase` [1].

--

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)

Comment: this code gives same result as code in the question. I wanted to sort paths like on the image attached. But anyway thank you for answer

Comment: Your image shows a _tree_. And even if we turn each "row" into a list item we would end up with a list mixing directories and files. I think that what's unclear in your question is that you do not want just "files after directories" but rather "files after directories **for each depth in the file hierarchy**". I would then suggest to mix 1) a Breadth First Search approach (see e.g. [this article](https://www.techiedelight.com/traverse-given-directory-bfs-dfs-java/)), 2) a recursive sort (to insert sorted content of a directory at the right place) and 3) the comparator proposed by hradecek.